# boost::thread pool and boost::bind or boost::function

Tags: boost, binding, bind, threadpool

How can i get return value from a boost thread pool?

i tried to attach a bound function to a boost::function:

```
boost::function f0; //void cause the parameter passed is always the same.

func = bind( static_cast(&MyClass::operator+),  this, arg );

MyClass obj;
threadpool.schedule( obj = &func() )
```

but it throws error: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments.

This is just the way i tried, it could be completely wrong...

**How can i get the return value of a bound function?** consider it has to be scheduled in a thread.
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: copy and past fail! first 2 lines are:                        boost::function funct< MyClass()>; //void cause the parameter passed is always the same.

func = bind( static_cast(&MyClass::operator+),  this, arg );

Comment: you should edit your question instead of adding a comment.

Comment: You can take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17941699/1578338).
it has a solution